# Single Page Application Data Not Showing in the View

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, single-page-application, durandal

I have a MVC 4 Single Page Application in which I can see data viewmodel's knockout code.  I do a foreach on in the view and can see a dot each time it goes through the loop, but the data is not displaying.  It looks as if the observable array has 50 elements, but no data in each.  Yet, when I step through the getJson call, I can see the data in json format.  What is wrong?

Here is my caapproval.html view code-

```
<section>
    <h2 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h2>

<br /> <br /> <br />

<ul data-bind="foreach: allCertificates">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: UserName"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: StatusCode"></span>
    </li>
</ul>

</section>
```

My caapproval.js viewmodel code-

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var Certificate = function (ClientID, RequestDate, UserName,                                                 StatusDescription, StatusCode,     StatusDesc, CEOUserName ) {
    var self = this;
    self.ClientID = ko.observable(ClientID);
    self.RequestDate = ko.observable(RequestDate);
    self.UserName = ko.observable(UserName);
    self.StatusDescription = ko.observable(StatusDescription);
    self.StatusCode = ko.observable(StatusCode);
    self.StatusDesc = ko.observable(StatusDesc);
    self.CEOUserName = ko.observable(CEOUserName);
};

var allCertificates = ko.observableArray();

var vm = {
    allCertificates: allCertificates,
    activate: activate,
    title: 'Certificates'
};


return vm;


function getallCertificates() {
    $.getJSON('/api/caapproval', function (data) {

        allCertificates([]);
        var temp = allCertificates();
        data.forEach(function (p) {
            var certificate = new Certificate(p.ClientID,  p.RequestDate, p.UserName, p.StatusDescription, p.StatusCode, p.StatusDesc, p.CEOUserName);
            temp.push(certificate);
        });

        allCertificates.valueHasMutated();
        return allCertificates();
    });

}

//#region Internal Methods
function activate() {
    logger.log('CA Approval View Activated!!', null, 'CA Approval',  true);
    return getallCertificates();
}
//#endregion

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I believe you are trying to push the results into the observableArray and not into a temporary holder for that data.  If that is the case I would suggest adjusting your code to the following -

```
function getallCertificates() {
    $.getJSON('/api/caapproval', function (data) {

        allCertificates([]);
        data.forEach(function (p) {
            var certificate = new certificateModel(p.ClientID,  p.RequestDate, p.UserName, p.StatusDescription, p.StatusCode, p.StatusDesc, p.CEOUserName);
            allCertificates.push(certificate);
        });
    });
}
```

You already set the observableArray to empty with ([]) so push the values back in there.  Also, Knockout knows the values have mutated when you set them and it is tracking them so there is no need to call valueHasMutated.

Next, I don't think you are intending to define your model inside of your view model like you are.  Take it outside of your model, or to a seperate JavaScript file entirely.  To improve your naming conventions I would recommend renaming certificate to certificateModel so it is more clear that this is not a function to do something, but a model instead.

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {

var allCertificates = ko.observableArray();

var vm = {
    allCertificates: allCertificates,
    activate: activate,
    title: 'Certificates'
};

return vm;

});

var certificateModel = function (ClientID, RequestDate, UserName, StatusDescription, StatusCode, StatusDesc, CEOUserName ) {
    var self = this;
    self.ClientID = ko.observable(ClientID);
    self.RequestDate = ko.observable(RequestDate);
    self.UserName = ko.observable(UserName);
    self.StatusDescription = ko.observable(StatusDescription);
    self.StatusCode = ko.observable(StatusCode);
    self.StatusDesc = ko.observable(StatusDesc);
    self.CEOUserName = ko.observable(CEOUserName);
};
```

Here is a jsFiddle more or less showing what you are trying to do.  jsFiddle does not support Durandal view model composition so I had to change it up a bit but the basic functionality is there.

http://jsfiddle.net/DwHXR/2/

Comment: I changed the viewmodel code, but still got the same problem.  No Data visible.  Then I changed the View code to what you sent in Fiddle and got the error 'router is not defined.

Comment: Router not defined is pretty clear but not in your code above.  Somewhere you mention durandals router but you never define it.

Comment: I found the issue.  In my original code- "return allCertificates();", The data was not being pushed into the allCertificates observable array.  The corrected code is "return allCertificates(data);."  I also had to add kadumel's certificateModel variable, and match the field names returned from my web api (they are case sensitive).  I also seperated my model from the view model code.  Thanks kadumel. You put me on the right track!